# Verification of Claims of being an incarnation

Tags: bhagavad-gita, avatars, ramakrishna

Let's get it straight, I ask for the views of the wise people here about Anukul Chandra. His devotees are somewhat hellbent on declaring him as the supreme, purushottomo. A few claims are listed below

1. If one is initiated to Anukul Chandra, there is no need to worship any other gods.  They go a step ahead to say that if one does take initiation, he/she becomes a disciple of Anukul Thakur and it would be blasphemy to consider anyone else as a guru.
2. Anukul Chandra says spiritualism is about living and letting others live. Every living being desires to live.
3. If you take Initiation, you have to offer a little bit of money to him, and at the end of the month send it to their organization.
4. His devotees claim he was the Kalki Avatar
5. All his descendants are considered to have divinity.
6. They say it was mentioned in Mahabharata, and other scriptures about his coming down to earth and so on.
7. He created Shiva Durga Kali, he is the supreme para Brahman.
8. He was Ramakrishna Paramahansa.
   I have read the principal Upanishads and the Gita, and although it seems to me that neither of the texts makes any prophecies, I would like to know if I have misinterpreted. I have also observed that some of his teachings are in contradiction to the teachings preached by the sages of Bharat. For example point 2) is not mentioned either in the Principal Upanishads or the Gita. In fact, Krishna says in the Gita that the wise, knowing the Immortality of the Atman, does not grieve for the living or the dead. Point 1) as well regarding blasphemy is not at terms with say The Great Ramakrishna Paramahansa, who was initiated to tantra by Bramhani, Non-dualism from Totapuri, Islam, Christianity, and whatnot.
   Please enlighten me about  Anukul Chandra if I am ignorant because I find all this nonsense. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Don't you think that this claim is very much idiotic and stupid. He can't be kalki avtar and no scripture support all these baseless claims

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, I think it's sheer nonsense.

Comment: Tell that guy to do some miracle lol. And, an actual miracle... let's say, tell him to create 2 tons of gold from thin air (that he won't make disappear). Otherwise it's just a stupid modern cult leader like Sadhuguru or Osho. I'd stay far away from him and anyone and anything affiliated with him if I were you.

Comment: That guy is dead and when he was alive he prophesied that for the next 10k years, his divinity would remain with his descendants. He is extremely popular among the not-so-educated people, people belonging to economically and socially backward communities, and they won't listen to anything against him. I am talking about  West Bengal in case it appears not so observed to you.

Comment: @CbbTtt Just ignore the cult and anyone associated with it. History proves that these sorts of cults die out within a hundred or two years, without institutional support.